# Determine image gamma by skipped levels

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

There are lots of scanners which allow to set image gamma in their settings, but unfortunately this gamma is adjusted in scanner software, not on the scanner side (by analog means or at least using ADC with more resolution than just 8 bits). Say, we get linear response from scanner initially, so 255 is maximal brightness, 128 is half as bright and so on, and then an image goes through a LUT:

```
0 -> 0,
1 -> 21,
2 -> 28
...
127 -> 186,
128 -> 186,
...
254 -> 255,
255 -> 255
```

Problem is: we get some bunch of scanned pages with unknown gamma settings and want to process them automatically, without close examination by human.

We'd like to detect images like that which have some particular brightness levels missing (here, with gamma=2,2 we miss 1..20, 22..27 etc.) and based on that to assign corresponding gamma value to the image, so it would be processed correctly afterwards. By the way, we would alert the user that information is lost because of this gamma conversion, so user should turn it off if possible.

It's pretty easy to determine this most common gamma=2.2 case, we just check corresponding zeroes. Gamma=1 is easy, too: in that case we should have no misses at all.

But it would be the most elegant solution to determine not just these cases, but arbitrary gamma by unique values missing. For example, gamma=1,01 has all the values except 20. In gamma = 1,2 (Plustek Opticbook scanner loves this value for grayscale images) we have 1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 12, ... missing, and so on.

There is a catch: some low and high values may be missing sometimes just because we have no extra white or extra black areas on the page, so we should cut off these 'tails' and work only with inner missed levels instead.

We may spend a lot of time building some sort of decision tree, but then all the processing should be as fast as possible: there are loads of these images with 600 dpi resolution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it's easier, I'm going to talk about levels from 0.0 to 1.0 instead of 0 to 255, so your gamma correction is like:

**out = in^(1/γ)**  or **in = out^γ**

In output brightness regions where you have enough pixels to detect the histogram zeros caused by gamma correction, the proportion of levels with no pixels depends on the relative slopes of the input and output curves.

**empty_level_proprotion(out) = max( 1 - din/dout , 0 )**

substituting **dout/din** gives us:

**empty_level_proprotion(out) = max( 1- (γ * out^(γ-1)) , 0 )**

For gamma 2.2 it looks like this:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+max(1-(2.2%2Ax%5E(1.2))+,+0)++from+0+to+1

This formula allows us to detect the applied gamma correction.  I would:

1. Divide the image histogram into 32 brightness bands
2. Drop all the bands that don't have enough pixels in them.  Require, say, 20 times as many pixels as there are distinct levels in the band
3. Calculate the number of levels in each band with no pixels
4. Fit the curves produced by the above formula against the remaining data to find the gamma value that best explains the data.

That should work pretty well if your original idea works. Note that there things that can mess it up:

- It doesn't work on JPEG-compressed images, because they will fill in the missing levels
- If the scanner did white-balance, contrast, or brightness fixes on the same 8-bit data before doing gamma correction, then those operations can mess up the data by introducing more missing levels.  This will basically just change the **1** above to a different value for each color channel, so you could detect this if you make your curve fitting more sophisticated.